# PL/SQL function return type integer : Invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a function called `get_pid` in a file called `func.sql` . The function `get_id` takes an 
input: `given_price Parts.price%type` and returns an integer.

To call this function, I created a new file called `main.sql`. Then I login to sqlplus and I call main in this way:

`SQL> @Q1_main
select get_pid(400) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "GET_PID": invalid identifier`

Am I calling the function properly? What could possibly be wrong, I looked at the other questions posted about this topic, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you compiled your function?

Comment: @EatÅPeach I don't think so, how do I do that?

Comment: the same way you ran the main.sql. Just run `@func.sql`

Comment: @EatÅPeach Ok thanks a million. Any idea on how I can compile it to give me the compilation errors?

Comment: Just run your script in sql prompt. If there are any compilation errors, run `show errors` and it will show the errors in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inform the name of the scheme where are your function.

for example, the username (schema) is dev, then you have to try like this.

select dev.get_pid(400) from dual.

Answer (score 0):

when you are on prompt you always have to use the scheme name "." your function/procedure.

Comment: While reading this answer it wasn't clear that you were trying to communicate that one needs to prepend the scheme name and a period before the function or procedure name.